# How to get current value show in listbox in a cell for an Open Office Macro?

Tags: openoffice-calc, uno, openoffice-basic

I am trying to yank the value from a listbox which is in a cell. Whenever I query the value however, it returns the first entry in the listbox, regardless of the current selection showing in the cell.

How do I access the current value displayed in the listbox?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If this one dropdown list for one cell, you could create a (hidden) list in a column. In the first cell of this list, you place a reference to the listbox cell.

e.g.

Column D
=A1
2nd FIXED value
3rd FIXED value
4th FIXED value

in A1, you put the dropdown with validity, cell list D1...D4.

Whatever you have in A1 will show up as a selectable option in your dropdown list.